# Would carbonated water be a good substitute for two eggs in this cherry loaf recipe?

Tags: baking, substitutions, bread, eggs, vegan

I would like to replace the two eggs in [this recipe](https://myislandbistrokitchen.com/2018/03/30/cherry-loaf-recipe/) with carbonated water:

Ingredients

1/3 cup shortening, butter, or margarine
¾ cup granulated sugar
¼ cup brown sugar, lightly packed
2 large eggs, room temperature
2/3 cup milk, room temperature
1½ tbsp orange juice, room temperature
2½ tbsp maraschino cherry juice, room temperature
1 tsp vanilla
¼ tsp almond flavouring
2¼ cups all-purpose flour
2 tsp baking powder
¼ tsp baking soda
¼ tsp salt
¾ cup maraschino cherries, well-drained, blotted dry, and coarsely chopped

Is carbonated water a good substitute for this? If it is, how much should I use to replace two eggs? Or does anyone have any suggestions of what I should use instead?

Comment: Why do you want to replace the eggs?

Comment: I like to bake things for my friend who is a vegan. :)

Comment: You'll also need to replace the milk then… & possibly the shortening.

Comment: In my experience, it is often better to specifically search for recipes that fit a certain diet or other requirements instead of trying to adapt one that doesn't, because such substitutions in baking can be difficult and if you get an already (hopefully) tested recipe you don't have to experiment as much.

Comment: I usually use recipes that are vegan already, but I cannot find any recipes similar to this. :(

Comment: I will use soy milk and use crisco butter shortening.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar to this"? If you want to replicate the flavorings, just add the juices/extracts and the cherries to any vegan cake recipe you like. If you want to replicate the texture, that won't work with all the substitutions you have to make.

Comment: The loaf cake recipes I found that are vegan already use 1 cup of soy milk and 1 tbsp vinegar, while this recipe only uses 2/3 cup milk. The vegan recipe also use s 1 tbsp of baking powder and 1/2 tsp baking soda. Maybe I will try to do that, and make sure to cream the shortening and sugars together longer than usual.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see the whole recipe, but the answer is probably no. Egg whites are protein and water, and yolks are fat, protein, and water, and each contributes important things to cakes. There is complicated chemistry going on, and you can't just eliminate the eggs from a recipe like this. Carbonation does nothing. However, if your recipe calls for, e.g., whipping the whites to create a stable foam, you could replace this with whipped aquafaba. There are other similar vegan substitutions that could be made depending on how your recipe is using the egg.

Comment: Here are the directions for the recipe:

Comment: In bowl of stand mixer fitted with paddle attachment and on low speed, cream the shortening, butter, or margarine well. Gradually add the granulated sugar, then the brown sugar. Increase mixer speed to medium and beat until ingredients are pale-colored and mixture has an airy/fluffy texture. Stop mixer, as necessary, to scrape bowl with rubber spatula to ensure the ingredients are evenly incorporated.
Add the eggs, one at a time, beating well after each addition and using the spatula, as necessary, to scrape sides of bowl.

Comment: https://myislandbistrokitchen.com/2018/03/30/cherry-loaf-recipe/?doing_wp_cron=1590055311.1770639419555664062500